# Alamofire Web service manager returns nil in viewController

Tags: ios, swift3, uiviewcontroller, alamofire

I want to create `AlamofireWebService` manager that contains all of my requests and I just use class functions of this class in my `viewControllers` and use responses in the `viewController`. 
For example something like this in `viewController`:

```
 let cardResponse : String?
 cardResponse = WebServiceManager.shared.getCardTitle()
```

I searched and found I should use escaping `completionHandler` in my function, And I wrote this:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class WebServiceManager {

    static let shared : WebServiceManager = WebServiceManager()

    let apiEndPoint = "My URL"

    func getCardTitle(completionHandler: @escaping (NSDictionary?, Error?) -> ()) {
        Alamofire.request("\(apiEndPoint)")
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .success(let value):
                      print("from .success \(value)")
                      completionHandler(value as? NSDictionary, nil)
                case .failure(let error):
                      completionHandler(nil, error)
                }
        }

    }
}
```

In success case, print works fine but in `viewController`, it just prints nil.

My `viewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    WebServiceManager.shared.getCardTitle() { responseObject, error in
        // use responseObject and error here

        print("responseObject = \(responseObject); error = \(error)")
        return
    }

}
```

What should I do to print in `viewController` print my response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that your value can't be cast to NSDictionary it has another type.

```
completionHandler(value as? NSDictionary, nil)
```

Please try in the manager a "pseudo code"

```
if let dic = value as? [String: Any] {
   debugPrint("Dic \(dic)")
} else  if let str = value as? String {
   debugPrint("String \(str)")
} else if let data = value as? Data, let str = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
   debugPrint("UTF8 String \(str)")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just check response nil

```
     Alamofire.request("URL", method: .post).responseJSON{(responseData) -> Void in
        if((responseData.result.value != nil)){
            let jsonData = JSON(responseData.result.value)

            if let arrJSON = jsonData["keyNodes"].arrayObject {

                for index in 0...arrJSON.count-1 {
                    let aObject = arrJSON[index] as! [String : AnyObject]
                    var sl:String;
                    if let sl1 = aObject["sl"] as? String {
                        sl = sl1;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I checked that as i said
response prints in success case

Comment: i think you are talking about you have found response from server & json response key is nil. right